# how to access dynamic/static movieclip with linked class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

hi this question still bothering me. It looks simple. 
I got movieclips in the lib and on stage which has a link-class "Box.as" and another which linked to "Circle.as".
I want to access the movieclip of the Box.as from the Circle.as or vice-versa.

```
public class Circle extends MovieClip
{
    private var _circle:MovieClip;
    private var _box:Box;


    public function Circle()
    {
        _circle = new MovieClip();

        if (stage) onStage();
        else this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onStage);


    }
    private function onStage(e:Event = null)
    {
        _circle = stage.getChildByName("blue_circle") as MovieClip;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hitTarget);

    }

    private function hitTarget(e:Event):void
    {

        if (_circle.hitTestObject(_box.mc)) //test if 2 movieclips are colliding
        { // _box.mc is just created the same as _circle
            trace("hi");
        }

    }
```

this code ain't workin. And I wanted to use one that can access even if the movieclip wasn't on stage(which has no instance name).
Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're really close! You just forgot to create a new instance of your class `Box`. So inside your `public function Circle()` just add

```
_box = new Box();
```

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't, there might be something wrong with your linking...

Your whole code will look like this

```
    public class Circle extends MovieClip
{
    private var _circle:MovieClip;
    private var _box:Box;


    public function Circle()
    {
        _box = new Box();
        _circle = new MovieClip();

        if (stage) onStage();
        else this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onStage);


    }
    private function onStage(e:Event = null)
    {
        _circle = stage.getChildByName("blue_circle") as MovieClip;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hitTarget);

    }

    private function hitTarget(e:Event):void
    {

        if (_circle.hitTestObject(_box.mc)) //test if 2 movieclips are colliding
        { // _box.mc is just created the same as _circle
            trace("hi");
        }

    }
```

Comment: oh! i'm sorry but i just forgot to add that in my post. But It was on the real code, still aint working. I also tried to trace the _box.mc or _circle but it traces null.

Comment: Well if you link correctly, I'm positive that's all you need, I've done it a million times. Double check that your classes are located in the correct packages, you capitlized correctly when linking variables and also saved your files with the correct names. Maybe also post the error you're getting. Is is saying can't access null object?

Comment: It's also possible you didn't import something...make sure you've made all the correct imports.......and one more thing to try. Try to addChild(_box) and then run your code and see if that at least works.